# Prisma and mongodb optional unique field throws "Unique constraint" error when empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unique, prisma, unique-constraint

I have the following models in prisma schema:

```
model Order {
  id                  String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  customer            User     @relation(fields: [customerId], references: [id])
  customerId          String   @db.ObjectId 
  products            Json
  status              String   @default("pending")
  paymentMethod       String?
  pixPayment          Payment? @relation(name: "pixPayment", fields: [pixPaymentId], references: [id])
  pixPaymentId        String?  @unique @db.ObjectId
  creditCardPayment   Payment? @relation(name: "creditCardPayment", fields: [creditCardPaymentId], references: [id])
  creditCardPaymentId String?  @unique @db.ObjectId
  boletoPayment       Payment? @relation(name: "boletoPayment", fields: [boletoPaymentId], references: [id])
  boletoPaymentId     String?  @unique @db.ObjectId
  total               Float
  createdAt           DateTime @default(now())

  @@map("Orders")
}

model Payment {
  id                     String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  paymentId              Int
  amount                 Float
  paymentMethod          String
  customer               User      @relation(fields: [customerId], references: [id])
  customerId             String    @db.ObjectId
  payer                  Json?
  installments           Int       @default(1)
  status                 String    @default("pending")
  dateOfExpiration       DateTime
  dateApproved           DateTime?
  barcode                String?
  boletoUrl              String?
  pixQrCode              String?
  pixQrCodeBase64        String?
  lastFourDigitsCard     String?
  cardHolder             Json?
  createdAt              DateTime  @default(now())
  pixPaymentOrder        Order?    @relation("pixPayment")
  creditCardPaymentOrder Order?    @relation("creditCardPayment")
  boletoPaymentOrder     Order?    @relation("boletoPayment")

  @@map("Payments")
}
```

I'm trying to create an Order document with the required fields (products, total, customerId), it works but only once, if I try to create another Order I get the error: "Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Orders_pixPaymentId_key`". The pixPaymentId is an unique and optional field and in this case I'm not passing it.
Order create code:

```
const order = await prisma.order.create({
            data: {
                products,
                total,
                customerId: userId
            },
            select: {
                id: true
            }
        });
```

I was expecting that would be possible to create multiple Orders documents without pixPaymentId as it is a OPTIONAL field, but I'm getting the Unique constraint error.

Comment: I would guess that Prisma leverages unique indexes in MongoDB to enforce this constraint. Such indexes allow only a single null/missing entry as you've discovered. You may need to manually (re)create the index in the database itself and additionally make it a partial index (where the desired field(s) exists) to achieve the behavior that you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Prisma doesn't support `unique and nullable` feature yet.

For this case, we can only declare it as `nullable` and handle uniqueness manually. Same problem will occur when implementing `unique and soft delete`.

The reason why they don't support it because most database reject duplicate NULLs on unique constraint.

Follow this discussion: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3387